# Can metadata properties of corrupted PDFs be extracted using python?

Tags: python, pdf, metadata

I have a large number of PDF files stored in a folder on my computer and I'm attempting to extract metadata from each of these files and create a dataframe with the information. However, I have encountered some corrupted PDFs in the folder. For my purposes, it would be extremely useful to extract metadata from these corrupted PDFs as well, rather than simply ignoring them. Is it possible to achieve this using Python?

Comment: Short answer: maybe. Longer short answer: yes, provided the metadata part of the PDF wasn't broken. Much longer answer: PDFs are just byte sequences, so as long as you're willing to implement the parser for it, at least up to the point where you have access to the metadata, Python will happily be the language you can do that with.

Comment: try to open the corrupted files with PyMuPDF. It has an automatic repair feature that can help in a lot of cases - e.g. by walking though the object definitions if the trailer was lost b/o an interrupted download. If this works, then you shoudl be able to also access the metadata `doc.metadata`.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of stock PDF MetaInfo is accessible via xpdf or poppler utilities, and usually included in Python installations. So if we scan recursively all files in a for loop then PDFInfo produces a well-structured output even for failing files.

```
>Apps\PDF\Xpdf\xpdf-tools-win-4.04\bin32\pdfinfo aa1.pdf
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
Syntax Warning: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...
Title:          *Untitled - Notepad
Author:
Producer:       Print My PDF
CreationDate:   Sun Jan  1 00:00:00 2023
ModDate:        Sun Jan  1 00:00:00 2023
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595.32 x 841.92 pts (A4) (rotated 0 degrees)
File size:      4416 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.7
```

Thus all we need to do is filter on our object of interest, such as what produced the file or what was the source document title?

Now the question is confined to Python and I don't use that, so you need to write lots of lines. I simply would run, at OS shell CMD level, a "findstr" (similar to Unix utils) and prefix the filename, using a loop in a batch, to output say as an example:

```
echo aa1.pdf & pdfinfo aa1.pdf  |findstr " Title:"

aa1.pdf
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
Syntax Warning: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...
Title:          *Untitled - Notepad
```